# Como simplificar o seguinte IF em PHP?

Tags: php, if

Tive que fazer uma verificação para concatenar conteúdo a uma variável, porém acho que o serviço ficou um tanto "porco" e queria ver se alguém poderia me ajudar a simplificar essa verificação

```
if($IdUserOnline2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= implode(',',$IdUserOnline2);
    if($IdUserComum2){
        $IdsInteracoes .= ','.implode(',',$IdUserComum2);
        if($IdUserNovo2){
            $IdsInteracoes .= ','.implode(',',$IdUserNovo2);
        }
    }elseif($IdUserNovo2){
        $IdsInteracoes .= ','.implode(',',$IdUserNovo2);
    }
}elseif($IdUserComum2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= implode(',',$IdUserComum2);
    if($IdUserNovo2){
        $IdsInteracoes .= ','.implode(',',$IdUserNovo2);
    }
}elseif($IdUserNovo2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= implode(',',$IdUserNovo2);
}
```

Comment: Nossa cara, você poderia explicar o que você queria fazer quando fez isto? desenvolver uma nova lógica com certeza vai ser melhor do que tentar corrigir esta(acredite) seria ótimo :D você pode editar sua pergunta com a intenção original?

Comment: A intenção ja esta explicita na própria pergunta, tenho que adicionar varios arrays a 1 só, porém, em dado momento preciso adicionar um prefixo contendo uma "," para separar os arrays e não bugar, após juntar os 3 terei uma string com todos eles e passo isso para um bind_param do mysqli.

Comment: Humm, Porque não adicionar todos os valores em um único Array e depois criar um laço de repetição para adicionar uma `,` em cada valor? as `,` sao por causa do sql né?

Comment: eu poderia fazer isso com array merge, mas se uma delas voltar vazia da erro na função, gerando uma cadeia de erros, a verificação tem que ser individual e a ação tambem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Há uma "hierarquia" entre "online", "comum" e "novo", por isso essa forma como você escreveu também é como eu escreveria... Mas no seu caso particular, vejo que o comportamento se repete seja dentro seja fora de cada `if`. Ou seja, basta substituir tudo por apenas 3 `if`s:

```
$prefixo = '';
if($IdUserOnline2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= implode(',',$IdUserOnline2);
    $prefixo = ',';
}

if($IdUserComum2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= $prefixo . implode(',',$IdUserComum2);
    $prefixo = ',';
}

if($IdUserNovo2){
    $IdsInteracoes .= $prefixo . implode(',',$IdUserNovo2);
}
```

Comment: @gmsantos PHP dá suporte a "ou" tal como em JavaScript? (ex.: `null || []` vira `[]`) Ou só se aplica a booleanos? Se for como no primeiro caso, você pode simplificar sua resposta usando essa forma simples dentro do próprio `array_merge` (usar o operador ternário não compensa nesse caso - ia ficar uma linha muito grande...). Nesse caso sua resposta de fato seria melhor que a minha (na minha opinião, tal como está a minha é mais clara/legível).

Answer (score 17):

Caso as chaves do seu *array* não se repitam entre eles você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$todosArrays = $IdUserOnline2 + $IdUserComum2 + $IdUserNovo2;
$IdsInteracoes = implode(',',$todosArrays);
```

Você pode também usar a função `array_merge` caso as chaves do *array* se repitam

```
$todosArrays = array_merge($IdUserOnline2, $IdUserComum2, $IdUserNovo2);
$IdsInteracoes = implode(',',$todosArrays);
```

Lembrando que, no caso do `array_merge`, verifique se as variáveis anteriores são *arrays*, evitando os erros:

```
$IdUserOnline2 = isset($IdUserOnline2) ? $IdUserOnline2 : array();
$IdUserComum2 = isset($IdUserComum2) ? $IdUserOnline2 : array();
$IdUserNovo2 = isset($IdUserNovo2) ? $IdUserOnline2 : array();

// É possível usar um ternário reduzido, porém é preciso inicializar as variáveis antes
// $IdUserOnline2 = $IdUserOnline2 ?: array();
// $IdUserComum2 = $IdUserComum2 ?: array();
// $IdUserNovo2 = $IdUserNovo2 ?: array();

$todosArrays = array_merge($IdUserOnline2, $IdUserComum2, $IdUserNovo2);
$IdsInteracoes = implode(',',$todosArrays);
```

A verificação das condições utilizam um [operador ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/uso-de-e-em-php).

A lógica é simples: Verifica se a variável existe, se ela não existir, inicializa ela como um *array* em branco. [Exemplo completo](https://gist.github.com/gmsantosxl/9687924).

---

**PHP 7+**

Foi implementado um novo operador no PHP 7 chamado [*Null Coalesce Operator*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), indicado para situações onde é preciso definir um valor padrão caso a expressão anterior retorne null.

Com ele, mesmo que a variável não esteja definida, o PHP **não** irá gerar um `Notice`, funcionando da mesma forma que o `||` do Javascript.

Assim poderíamos simplificar o código acima para:

```
$IdUserOnline2 = $IdUserOnline2 ?? [];
$IdUserComum2 = $IdUserComum2 ?? [];
$IdUserNovo2 = $IdUserNovo2 ?? [];

$todosArrays = array_merge($IdUserOnline2, $IdUserComum2, $IdUserNovo2);
$IdsInteracoes = implode(',',$todosArrays);
```

Comment: `$IdsInteracoes=implode(',',array_merge($IdUserOnline2,$IdUserComum2,$IdUserNovo2));` Bem mais simples assim

Comment: Não tinha reparado ainda, mas se uma das variaveis vier vazia da erro nessas funções, então me geraria uma nova hierarquia de verificações que no caso não simplifica o if

Comment: o problema é que eu fiz isso e mesmo assim ele me retornou erro no array_merge, pois de uma forma ou de outra ela iria pro array_merge vazia, verificando ou não

Comment: Nesse caso não, pois o ternário define a variável como um array vazio **caso** ela não esteja definida.

Comment: Explique melhor, de onde vem essas três variáveis? Elas podem assumir um valor diferente de um `array`? `string` por exemplo?

Comment: as 3 vem do banco de dados, logo tenho 3 arrays diferente, que são usuarios de categorias diferentes, preciso juntas todos os usuarios listados nas 3 categorias em uma lista para usar em um bind_param do mysqli ja que o mesmo não aceita arrays, logo preciso juntar os 3 em uma string para usar dentro de uma função IN do SQL

Comment: @RodrigoBorth o erro de sua função (2º comentário) vem do `isset()`, como expliquei acima. Se as variável **sempre** estiverem definidas, o código não gera notice.

Comment: Gostei dessa modificação no PHP 7. Facilita bastante a vida

Comment: Pode-se forçar as variáveis a serem arrays para não precisar verificar se estão vazias `$IdsInteracoes = implode(',', array_merge((array) $IdUserOnline2, (array) $IdUserComum2, (array) $IdUserNovo‌​2));`

Comment: @Oeslei mesmo assim gera notice http://3v4l.org/LmNJ8

Comment: @gmsantos A forma que coloquei serve apenas para quando todas as variáveis estão definidas, mas que possivelmente possuam valores como `null` ou `false`. Quando as mesmas não estão definidas é necessário o `isset`, mas analisando a pergunta, presumo que as variáveis já estejam definidas, caso contrário a própria solução inicial já gera erro.

Comment: @Oeslei leia os comentários nessa pergunta.

Comment: +1 pela versão do PHP 7, não sabia disso. :S