# Uso de ? e : em PHP

Tags: php, operadores

Podem me explicar para que serve `?` e `:` em PHP?

Por exemplo neste caso:

```
public function url_format($post,$extra=FALSE) {    
    $title = isset($post->post_title) ? $post->post_title : $post->title;
    $title = isset($post->url) ? $post->url : $title;
    return $lang_domin.strtolower(url_title($title)).'-postid-'.$post->id.$extra;
}
```

Comment: Possíveis duplicatas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9962/como-simplificar-o-seguinte-if-em-php/ ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3647/quando-usar-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-tern%C3%A1ria ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Isto é chamado [operador condicional ou ternário](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Ele funciona como um `if`. Ele testa uma condição (o primeiro operando), se ela for verdadeira, o resultado da operação é o primeiro valor (após o `?`, o segundo operando), se ela for falsa, então o resultado é o segundo valor (depois do `:` , o terceiro operando).

Note que ele não pode [executar comandos, só pode ter expressões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101). Nem sempre é recomendável usá-lo já que ele pode dificultar a legibilidade. Mas na maioria das vezes onde você tem apenas uma expressão simples e curta como resultado, quando não aninha um operador ternário com outro e quando não exige ficar colocando vários parênteses para desambiguar o que está fazendo, ele fica mais curto e muito fácil de entender. Algumas pessoas são contra ele sempre mas eu acho exagero. Ele é bem útil em muitos casos. Dizer que nunca deve usá-lo é tão ruim quanto dizer que sempre deve usá-lo.

O nome condicional vem justamente porque ele deve testar uma condição para saber qual é o resultado da sua operação (da sua "conta"). E ele também é chamado de ternário porque ele é o único operador com três operandos. O dia que criarem outro - eu duvido que aconteça - vai dar confusão :)

Há uma explicação com mais detalhes em outras perguntas como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4907/101) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3647/101). A linguagem pode ser diferente mas a ideia é a mesma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, deixou bem claro o que queria saber ;)

Comment: @bigown vai editar a resposta com o teste de desempenho ou vai criar outra ? raramente encontro códigos em php usando esse operador, vejo mais isto em C++

Comment: Há algum ganho de performance ao se utilizar operador ternário ao invés de um operador condicional?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues raramente encontra porque a maioria dos programadores PHP não conhecem bem a linguagem ou tem preconceito com o recurso. Mas eu não vou editar a resposta porque a pergunta não fala em performance. Teria que ser outra pergunta para manter o foco.

Comment: @EduardoSilva eu tenho o teste pronto mas não tenho **pergunta** perguntando isto, se algém postar, eu respondo :P

Comment: @bigown, fiz uma pergunta, segue: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56830/h%C3%A1-algum-ganho-de-performance-ao-se-utilizar-operador-tern%C3%A1rio-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-um-op

Answer (score 20):

No teu exemplo, o mesmo faz uso de um operador condicional cuja condição é separada dos resultados pelo caractere `?` e os resultados separados entre si pelo caractere `:`.

## O que é um operador condicional "?:"

Um operador condicional, como o próprio nome indica, é um operador que opera com base numa condição.

Faz parte do grupo de operadores ternários porque leva três operandos: uma condição, um resultado para verdadeiro, e um resultado para falso.

Na sua essencia, é uma forma simples de sumariar verificações tornando o código mais compacto:

```
if ("condição") {
  $bubu = "sim";
}
else {
  $bubu = "não";
}
```

Transforma-se em:

```
$bubu = "condição" ? "sim" : "não";
```

Neste operador, a avaliação da condição retorna sempre um [boleano](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booliano) que despoleta a utilização do primeiro valor em caso `TRUE` ou segundo valor em caso `FALSE`.

Este operador é também conhecido pelos seguintes nomes:

- IF condicional
- *Shorthand* IF
- *Inline* IF
- *Ternary operator* (operador ternário)

### Vantagens

- Torna a programação da lógica de simples `if` / `else` mais rápida
- Reduz a quantidade de código
- Torna a manutenção do código mais fácil
- Permite o uso da lógica *inline* evitando partir o código em múltiplas linhas:

  ```
  echo "Bem vindo, ".($loginAtivo?$primeiroNome:"Convidado").".";
  ```

### Desvantagens

Salvo o excesso do seu uso, o operador condicional não apresenta desvantagens. A sua própria criação partiu do principio de simplificar pequenas ações lógicas.

Um exemplo do seu uso de forma desvantajosa onde a manutenção do código se torna um pesadelo:

```
// Devolve os dias em determinado mês
$dias = ($mes == 2 ? ($ano % 4 ? 28 : ($ano % 100 ? 29 : ($ano %400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($mes - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31));
```

O exemplo em cima é uma utilização incorreta deste operador porque a leitura do código é difícil, tornando-se mais completo do que o regular `if~else`.

### Erros comuns

E comum referir-nos a este operador como `operador ternário`, apesar de ser um operador condicional do grupo de operadores ternários, porque na linguagem PHP, é o único que existe. <sup>(?)</sup>

> Another conditional operator is the "?:" (or ternary) operator.

Que traduzido:

> Outro operador condicional é o "?:" (ou ternário) operador.

A própria [documentação do PHP para este operador](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) leva-nos a fazer uso do nome `operador ternário`, que, conforme [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56814/223):

> O dia que criarem outro - eu duvido que aconteça - vai dar confusão :)

## PHP > 5.3

A partir do PHP versão 5.3, é possível reduzir ainda mais o código, deixando de fora a parte do meio `expr1 ?: expr3`:

```
$bubu = "sim" ?: "não";
```

Vai devolver a primeira expressão se a mesma avalia para `TRUE`, caso contrário devolve a terceira expressão.

*A utilização nesta forma já não será tão comum, mas para ter sido implementada, deve dar jeito em algum momento.*

Comment: Tem como fazer um if elseif else utilizando  operador condicional?

Comment: @JulioHenrique tem sim https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/523100/187610

Answer (score 17):

É um **[operador ternário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)**, a expressão `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` é avaliada para `expr2` se `expr1` é avaliada como `TRUE`, ou `expr3` se `expr1` é avaliada como `FALSE`.

Seria o mesmo que:

```
public function url_format($post,$extra=FALSE) {
   if(isset($post->post_title)){
      $title = $post->post_title;
   } else {
      $title = $post->title;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Isto não responde a pergunta, poderia melhorar?

Comment: Me desculpe @GuilhermeNascimento mais discordo, isto responde exatamente a pergunta de forma clara.

Comment: é responde, mas não como funciona, apenas indica um link, você poderia ter copiado algo do link ao meu ver, mas é apenas uma opinião e sugestão para você melhorar a sua resposta, fica a seu critério aceitar ou não, um trecho legal a adicionar seria: *A expressão (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) é avaliada para expr2 se expr1 é avaliada como TRUE, ou expr3 se expr1 é avaliada como FALSE.*

Comment: Ok, @GuilhermeNascimento agradeço a sugestão, assim que tiver um tempo melhoro a resposta.

Comment: Fiz uma edição, fique a vontade para fazer o rollback se discordar, não irei ficar chateado :) +1 para sua resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento De maneira alguma, sua edição é bastante pertinente

Answer (score 1):

### Vale ressaltar a estrutura condicional `if`, `elseif` e `else` em ternário!

Isto é, caso queira duas ou mais expressões, sem requer o uso do `if`, `elseif`, `else` ou `switch case` basta seguir o padrão de acordo com a documentação [**operadores de comparação**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```php
condicao ? true : (condicao ? false : (condicao ? null) ...)
```

Segue os exemplos abaixo:

```php
function func($value) {
    return $value == "a" ? true : ($value == "b" ? false : ($value == "sopt" ? "stack overflow em português" : null));
}

print func("sopt"); // stack overflow em português
```

<sup>Contudo, evite *empilhar* as expressões ternárias, para não acabar caindo no comportamento **não-óbvio**! [teste o código](https://onlinephp.io/c/fdc07)</sup>

- ##### `if else`

```php
function func($value) {
    if ($value === "a") {
        return true;
    } elseif ($value === "b") {
        return false;
    } elseif ($value === "sopt") {
        return "stack overflow em português";
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

- ##### `switch case`

```php
function func($value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case "a":
            return true;
        case "b":
            return false;
        case "sopt":
            return "stack overflow em português";
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

Portanto, veja qual adéqua-se mais ao seu código. Em relação a performance (*[referente ao comentário..](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56814/187610)*), se há alguma diferença, ela é **insignificante**! Apesar da legibilidade e um código limpo ao usar ternário.