# Preciso de explicação sobre o que um código que não entendo faz

Tags: php, html, operadores

Preciso fazer uma mudança em um código e encontrei isso: 
`<?=(((++$i % 2) == 1) ? 'class="colored"' : '')?>`

O que esse código faz?

Comment: Isso é um [**operador ternario**](http://www.phpmais.com/o-operador-ternario-em-php-um-guia-pratico/), faz  semelhante ao que o `if...else` faz.

Comment: Isso não está em um laço de repetição(`for` ou `while`), não? Tem um operador de incremento junto.

Comment: Não está em um laço não!

Comment: Isso fora de um laço não tem qualquer utilidade, porque o `++$i` _(pré incrementado)_ deve ser iterado para que o seu valor mude. - [Exemplo](http://pastebin.com/JUhbm5Qc)

Comment: O código é exatamente esse:  `<tr <?=(((++$i % 2) == 0) ? 'class="colored"' : '')?>>`

Comment: Acontece que eu tenho outra tr embaixo dessa, e eu preciso que esse código de tabelas zebradas inclua a tr de baixo para a mudança de cores.

Comment: Cria uma outra pergunta, para que possamos responder, está aqui já possui demasiadas respostas relacionadas a um problema específico.

Comment: Mas para uma resposta rápida, podes usar isto na folha de estilos - `table tr:nth-child(even) {color:violet;}`, ou dentre as tags `style`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É um ternário que verifica se `$i` é um número impar utilizando o módulo de dois, se positivo retorna um pedaço de html que é a definição de uma classe(css) do contrario uma string vazia é retornada.

O simbolo (`<?=`) no início serve para imprimir o resultado da expressão ele é equivalente a `<?php echo 'algo';`

```
((++$i % 2) == 1) ? 'class="colored"' : '';
 | 1 | 
 |  2           | 3 caso seja impar   | 4 caso seja par
```

1 - Pré incremento de `$i` ou seja ele terá seu valor incrementado antes de relizar o cálculo do módulo.

2 - Calculo do módulo de dois caso retorne 1 significa que o número é impar, caso seja zero é par.

3 - Condição true.

4 - Condição false.

É provável que esse fragmento de código tenha sido extraido de algo como:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
    <tr <?=(((++$i % 2) == 1) ? 'class="colored"' : '');?>>
        <td><?=$row['nome'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['descricao'];?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: acho interessante comentar sobre os short tag `<?=` = echo

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, valeu passei direto nisso, já edito adicionando essa informação

Answer (score 13):

Ele incrementa a variável `$i` divide por 2 e pega o resto. Se o resto for 1 - se é ímpar - ele usa a *string* `'class="colored"'`, senão usa uma *string* vazia. No caso ele está atribuindo a classe quando o contador é ímpar, ou seja, provavelmente está fazendo uma tabela zebrada, mas não dá para afirmar sem mais detalhes. Se não está em um laço isto parece estar muito errado.

Isto é o [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56812/101). Junto com o [operador de pré-incremento](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Comment: Ele atribui a classe a cada novo item que a lista recebe. Eu preciso que ele atribua a cada 2 itens que a lista receber. Como posso fazer?

Comment: É exatamente isso, desculpa não dar mais detalhes mas é isso mesmo!!

Comment: Precisa que use em 2 itens, aí 2 fica sem, depois volta ter em 2, etc.? Ou precisa um sim e um não?

Comment: Preciso do seguinte: Essa tabela possui itens etc. Alguns itens tem o campo "Nota" embaixo do item, quando houver nota quero que o campo nota fique da mesma cor do item acima, quando não houver nota preciso que continuem alternando cores a cada novo item.

Comment: @TiagoP.C Apenas com o código que você informou, impossivel te ajudar, poste o restante do código da sua tabela zebrada e da logica dela na sua pergunta.

Comment: @TiagoP.C Só com estes detalhes não dá para responder. Como já tem várias repostas, esta pergunta já está comprometida. Agora só resta você fazer outra pergunta mostrando seu código real, dar detalhes de como está funcionando e o que pretende. Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok @bigown, muito obrigado pelas respostas, já foi de grande ajuda, farei outra pergunta com parte do código!

Answer (score 3):

É em uma tabela que 
em uma linha pinta de uma cor e
na próxima linha de outra cor
e vai alternando.

Comment: Exatamente! Eu preciso que ele pinte a cada duas linhas, como fazer?

Comment: @TiagoP.C Você perguntou o que o código faz. E isso já foi respondido. Sugiro que abra uma nova pergunta e explique o que você precisa.