# Update Mysql só de colunas Vazias

Tags: php, mysql

Existe alguma forma de se fazer uma um Update no mysql onde só deixe fazer a atualização dos dados se a coluna estiver vazia.

- Imagina 4 input radio (os radios ´so marcão 1 por vez não é)
- Ai se um usuário(x) escolher o  radio 1 e salva, e o usuário(y) escolhe o radio 2 e salva
- Ai Oque acontece com o input radio 1 ???? o post vem vazio consequentemente apagando o dado no mysql e isso que não quero que ocorra

Exemplo

Tabela dados

```
         __________________________________________
        | id |  valor1  | valor2 | valor3 | Valor4 | 
        |  1 |    20    |        |   20   |        |

    $valor1 = $_post['valor1']; //post vasio
    $valor2 = $_post['valor2']; //post vasio
    $valor3 = $_post['valor3']; //post vasio
    $valor4 = $_post['valor4']; //post vasio

    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dados(valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4)
    VALUES('$valor1','$valor2','$valor3','$valor4',)", 
    $conexao) or die( mysql_error());

    se os post vierem vazios, vão apagar os dados que já estão na base
```

Na coluna valor1 e valor3 consta valores inseridos, eu gostaria de uma forma de travar esses valores e não deixar trocalo

Comment: Dê uma conferida se este não é um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). Pode ser que as respostas sejam mais útes colocando na pergunta o problema inicial a ser resolvido.

Comment: Como @bacco disse em seu comentário, você está procurando uma solução incorreta para o seu problema. O MySQL não permite esse tipo de bloqueio.
Você deve validar isso com o próprio php em tela. seja atualizando as informações na hora de salvar ou reestruturando a modelagem de seu banco de dados que está me parecendo confusa

Comment: O update melhorou um pouco a pergunta, mas revelou um problema: guardar um input radio em 4 colunas diferentes provavelmente é desnecessário. Outro problema é que você não testa no seu código se foi enviado algum post ou não. Mais um problema é que seu código é um INSERT, nem sequer faz sentido falar em colunas vazias. O insert sempre cria uma linha nova. Sugeriria voltar uns passos no seu desenvolvimento e consertar estas coisas (dominar os conceitos) antes de prosseguir, pois quanto mais avança mais confuso o código fica, e vai cada vez mais demandar remendos.

Comment: Com a modificação, a minha resposta fica sem sentido. E o problema em si também. Parece ser mais um problema de lógica de negócio. Algo +- conforme o @Ari comentou.

Answer (score 2):

1) Não use as funções `mysql()` do PHP. Estão obsoletas desde a versão 5.5.X e foram removidas do PHP 7, então, não as use. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

2) Se você não quer inserir os valores, então, não os mande para o banco de dados, ora.

`INSERT INTO dados(valor2, valor4) VALUES('$valor2','$valor4')`

O mesmo vale pra o `UPDATE`. Se não quer alterar um valor, não altere:

`UPDATE dados SET`valor2`= '$valor2',`valor4`= '$valor4'`

3) Os input do tipo radio só serão excludentes (marca ou um ou outro) se tiverem o mesmo nome.

```html
<form name="exemplo" action="pagina.php" method="POST">
  <!-- selecione um genero -->
  <p>Qual o seu gênero? </p>
  <input type="radio" name="genero" value="masculino"> Masculino<br>
  <input type="radio" name="genero" value="feminino"> Feminino<br><br>
  <!-- selecione somente um -->
  <p>Gosta de matemática? </p> 
  <input type="radio" name="math" value="sim"> Sim<br>
  <input type="radio" name="math" value="nao"> Não<br>
</form>
<!-- \ fim do form -->
```

4) Você pode fazer uma consulta no banco de dados pra verificar se os campos estão vazios:

```
<?php
//abra a conexao com banco de dados
$conexao = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco_de_dados');

//faca uma consulta
$consulta = "SELECT `valor1`, `valor3` FROM `dados` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1";
//execute sua query
$executar = $conexao->query($consulta);
//retornar o resultado da execucao
while ($dados = $executar->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
    $valor1 = $dados['valor1'];
    $valor3 = $dados['valor3'];
}
//confere se os valores estao vazios
if($valor1 == '' AND $valor3 == ''){
    //atualiza os dois campos aqui
}
```

Obviamente você terá mais duas condições: se o valor1 estiver vazio e o 3 não e se o valor3 estiver vazio e o 1 não.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos reformular sua pergunta:

Quero manter um dado fixo e somente alterar se houver um POST.
É isso?

Utilize algo similar a isso:

```
<?php

// Pega os  dados já existentes baseado no ID, que deve pelo menos haver alguma colisão com o usuário logado, se não nada faz sentido.

$fixo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados WHERE id = '$id'");
$fixo = mysql_fetch_array($fixo);

// Se houver post
if($_POST['valor1']){$valor1 = $_POST['valor1'])else{$valor1 = $fixo['valor1']};
if($_POST['valor2']){$valor2 = $_POST['valor2'])else{$valor2 = $fixo['valor2']};
if($_POST['valor3']){$valor3 = $_POST['valor3'])else{$valor3 = $fixo['valor3']};
if($_POST['valor4']){$valor4 = $_POST['valor4'])else{$valor4 = $fixo['valor4']};

// Desta forma sempre irá ser o valor já existente como padrão, se houver um POST será o valor a ser inserido.

// Exemplo:
// Se houver POST valor1 de 100 será 100.
// Se não houver POST valor2 irá pegar o valor do banco de dados, assim irá mante-lo.

mysql_query ("UPDATE dados SET valor1 = $valor1, valor2 = $valor2, valor3 = $valor3, valor4 = $valor4 WHERE id = '$id'");
// Irá atualizar onde o id for  igual ao id.
// Se preferir utilize INSERT:
// mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dados(valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4)    VALUES('$valor1','$valor2','$valor3','$valor4')");
?>
```

Se quiser apenas utilizar o POST se o dado do bando estiver vazio utilize:

```
if($fixo['valor1'] == ''){$valor1 = $_POST['valor1'])else{$valor1 = $fixo['valor1']};
if($fixo['valor2'] == ''){$valor2 = $_POST['valor2'])else{$valor2 = $fixo['valor2']};
if($fixo['valor3'] == ''){$valor3 = $_POST['valor3'])else{$valor3 = $fixo['valor3']};
if($fixo['valor4'] == ''){$valor4 = $_POST['valor4'])else{$valor4 = $fixo['valor4']};
```

Desta forma quando o query for formado será: `SET valor1 = valor1` por exemplo, o que não irá mudar.

**Notas:**

> O mysql_* está obsoleto, se está aprendendo ou no começo do desenvolvimento comece a usar o mysqli (ou PDO, mas o mysqli seria suficiente!).
>
> Não há motivos para ter várias colunas para este tipo de `input`, na minha opinião.
>
> Se você está inserindo uma nova linha (INSERT), como está "apagando"?!

Comment: Só uma dica: o ternário deixa isso muito mais legivel:  `$valor1 = isset( $_POST['valor1'] ) ? $_POST['valor1'] : $fixo['valor1'];` http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/uso-de-e-em-php

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, o MySQL detecta um valor existente. Caso encontre, não o modifica. Por isso não há necessidade em fazer um SELECT para buscar onde há campos vazios.

Você pode verificar isso no retorno de [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Faça um teste simples tentando atualizar com dados já existentes e poderá ver que [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) retorna vazio.

O que poderia ser feito para otimizar é simplesmente evitar o envio de dados que não foram modificados. Para isso, crie algum controle client-side, com JavaScript, por exemplo. Há técnicas diversas. Poderá usar cookies, por exemplo. A ideia é salvar os valores originais do formulário assim que entra na página. Quando o usuário enviar o formulário, antes de submeter, seria feito uma verificação do que foi modificado. O que não for modificado, remova do formulário e envie só o que foi anterado. O interessante nisso é, caso conste que nada foi modificado, interrompa o envio e exiba uma mensagem ao usuário dizendo que nada foi modificado e, por esse motivo, os dados não serão enviados.

Assim evitará custo com tráfego de dados, o que já é ótimo. E de quebra, ainda "alivia" o MySQL de ter que verificar se um valor já existe ou não naquela coluna específica.

**Nota adicional, não relacionada a pergunta**

Evite funções em desuso. Troque as funções [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) por [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)