# Inserir um loop dentro de outro loop

Tags: javascript, loop, for

Desejo intercalar o segundo com o primeiro.

Para ilustração, vou utilizar o simples exemplo abaixo como base:

```
<script>
  n = 10;
  for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++){document.body.innerHTML += i;}

  for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++){c = String.fromCharCode(i+64);document.body.innerHTML += c;}
</script>
```

> Resumindo, quero colocar o segundo loop dentro do primeiro, de modo que fique **2 em 1** tornando-se um código compacto, mas funcional.

Comment: Não entendi o que está querendo, se quer que um laço depois do outro, está certo, não tem o que inventar. Se quer outra coisa, não está claro. Você quer que ambos executam as duas linhas de código concomitante, ou seja, juntas? Tem alguma dificuldade em passar uma linha de um bloco pra dentro do outro?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como deve aparecer no HTML? não é claro para mim o que pretendes ter como resultado.

Comment: Diego, viste a minha pergunta ^ ?

Comment: @Diego veja se faltou alguma coisa, e deixe um comentário aqui, pq se você precisar entender algo que eu não pus na resposta, ou mais explicações dos exemplos, posso tentar ajudar e esclarecer melhor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Segue versão com intercalação, depois da edição da pergunta**:

```js
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   document.body.innerHTML += i + String.fromCharCode(i+64);
}
```

Dá no mesmo que:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   document.body.innerHTML += i;
   document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCharCode( i + 64 );
}
```

**Se fosse fazer uma matriz**:

Dois loops um dentro do outro seriam mais adequados para fazer uma matriz:

```js
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
      document.body.innerHTML += i + String.fromCharCode( j + 64 ) + ' ';
   }
   document.body.innerHTML += '<br>'; // quebra de linha pra facilitar a leitura
}
```

**Se fosse fazer operações sequenciais**:

```js
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){document.body.innerHTML+=i<10?i:String.fromCharCode(i+54);}
```

Ou seja, em vez de dois loops de 0 a 9, temos um de 0 a 19.

- Se for de 0 a 9, o ternário `i<10?` vai acrescentar `i` na página.
- senão, vai acrescentar `String.fromCharCode(i+54)`. Note que eu mudei para 54, para descontar a diferença da posição do loop. Se não quiser a `@`, basta usar 55;

Ou seja, em vez de dois loops de 0 a 9, temos um de 0 a 19.

Só pra ficar mais didático, segue uma versão da primeira versão mais simples de ler, mas que funciona exatamente da mesma maneira:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
  if( i < 10 ) {
    // Aqui faz a parte do 1o loop
    document.body.innerHTML += i; 
  } else {
    // Aqui faz a parte do 2o loop
    document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCharCode( i - 10 + 64 );
  }
}
```

Para entender o `if` que está "escondido" no primeiro código, basta ver esta pergunta:

> [Uso de ? e : em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/)

A linguagem é outra, mas o funcionamento do `? :` é o mesmo.