# Gerar um row depois de 2 colunas no bootstrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu consegui uma forma de gerar um *row* depois de duas colunas no bootstrap, mas o resultado não ficou como preciso.

Tenho isso:

```
<?php
$sql_3 = mysql_query("SELECT id, razao_social, cep, cidade, uf, rua, numero, bairro, complemento, logo, CodCli FROM tb_empresas") or die(mysql_error());

if (@mysql_num_rows($sql_3) <= '0')
    {
    echo "";
    }
  else
    {
    while ($r_sql_3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_3))
        {
        $id_empresa = $r_sql_3[0];
        $razao_social = $r_sql_3[1];
        $cep = $r_sql_3[2];
        $cidade = $r_sql_3[3];
        $uf = $r_sql_3[4];
        $rua = $r_sql_3[5];
        $numero = $r_sql_3[6];
        $bairro = $r_sql_3[7];
        $complemento = $r_sql_3[8];
        $logo = $r_sql_3[9];
        $cod_cli = $r_sql_3[10];
        $endereco = $rua . ", " . $numero . ", " . $bairro . ", " . $cidade . " - " . $uf;
        $endereco_exibe = substr($endereco, 0, 14);
        $sql_3_1 = mysql_query("SELECT telefone FROM tb_empresas_tel WHERE CodCli = '$cod_cli' AND id_emp = '$id_empresa' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        if (@mysql_num_rows($sql_3_1) <= '0')
            {
            echo "";
            }
          else
            {
            while ($r_sql_3_1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_3_1))
                {
                $telefone = $r_sql_3_1[0];
                $telefone_exibe = substr($telefone, 0, 9);
                }
            }

?>

    <div class="vc_col-lg-6">
        <article class="eltd-listing-list-item" id="<?php
        echo $id_empresa; ?>">
            <div class="eltd-listing-item-content">
                <a class="eltd-listing-item-image-link" href="#" title="#">
                                                            <img width="800" height="600" src="images/logos_clientes/<?php
        echo $logo; ?>" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="<?php
        echo $razao_social; ?>" title="<?php
        echo $razao_social; ?>" />

                                                            <div class="icone_empresas_wrapper_mapa icone_empresas">
                                                                <a class="icone_empresas" href="#" style="background-color:#ff6936 !important;">
                                                                    <i class="flaticon-food item_opc_1_emp"></i>                
                                                                </a>
            </div>
            </a>

            <div class="eltd-listing-title-holder">
                <a href="#" title="#">
                    <h3 class="eltd-listing-title" style="font-family: 'Radikal-Bold'; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 10px 0 0 0;">
                        <?php
        echo $razao_social; ?>
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="categoria_exp">
                <a href="#">Categoria > Saúde > Clínica ondontológica</a>
            </div>

            <div class="empre_tel">
                <a href="#"><span><?php
        echo $telefone_exibe; ?>...</span> Ver telefone</a>
            </div>

            <div class="categoria"></div>
            <span class="eltd-listing-item-address">
                                                            <a href="#"><span><?php
        echo $endereco_exibe; ?> </span> ... Ver endereço</a>
            </span>
    </div>
    </article>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    }

?>
```

Funciona corretamente.
Mas preciso que gere um *row* depois de duas colunas, pois os blocos ficam desalinhados, por não conterem as mesmas informações.

Alguém já viu algo, ou tem alguma ideia para uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa de um row a cada dois elementos basta contar a quantidade de elemento.

No caso, se é somente a cada 2 elementos pode utilizar o comparador usando a operação de `$X % 2 === 0`. O operador `%` obtêm o resto da divisão, dessa forma podemos usa-lo para saber se é *par* ou é *impar*.

Quando dividimos por 2 teremos o resto. Se o resto for `0` é porque é disível por `2` e portanto é *par*. Enquanto se for *impar* irá restar `1`. Como na matemática a divisão de 0 por qualquer número é sempre `0` então o mesmo se aplica, ele será considerado *par* nosso sistema. ;P

Para exemplificar o funcionamento do `%`, antes que entenda errado:

```
14 % 3 => 2 (12, do 3*4, é o maior alcançado, sobrando 2)
2 % 2 => 0 (2, do 2*1, é o maior alcançado, sobrando 0)
7 % 2 => 1 (6, do 2*3, é o maior alcançado, sobrando 1)
29 % 5 => 4 (25, do 5*5,é o maior alcançado, sobrando 4)
```

**Logica:**

Se o elemento atual for *par* ele inicia o `row` (`<div class="row">`). Na condição dele ser *impar* ou o último elemento *par* deve fechar o `row` (`</div>`).

**Então basta que adicione:**

```
if($i %2 === 0){    
 echo '<div class="row">';
}

//...

if($i %2 !== 0 || count($array) === $i + 1){    
    echo '</div>';
}
```

[Veja isto funcionando clicando aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f91fd02ff6c268033eba2230f7951d91e0862bf3)

Dessa forma se for *par* ele irá adiciona a `div` e se não ele irá fechar, entretanto se o *par* for o último elemento ele irá fechar também.

**O seu código é longo para fazer tão poucas alterações, tonariam imperceptível, portanto basta que adicione:**

Um `$i` no inicio do código:

```
<?php
// Acrescente um $i:
$i = 0;
```

No fim do while acrescente:

```
   <?php
   // Adicione:
   $i++;
}
```

Então no HTML poderá adicionar:

```
<?= ($i % 2 === 0) ? '<div class="row">' : '' ?>
   <div class="vc_col-lg-6">
   //....
   </div>
<?= ($i % 2 !== 0 || count($array) === $i + 1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
```

> O `<?=` no PHP 5.4+ está ativo por padrão, ele é igual ao `<? echo`, [comparador ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/uso-de-e-em-php) faz o mesmo que o `if` apresentado lá em cima, com menos código.

---

**Observações:**

*Isso não está na questão perguntada, mas acho importante dizer.*

Não use `mysql_` migre para o `mysqli_`, [veja aqui o porque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql).

Além disso você está sempre usando:

```
$id_empresa = $r_sql_3[0];
$razao_social = $r_sql_3[1];
//...
```

Não vejo sentido para isso se você pode simplesmente utilizar: `$r_sql_3['id']` e `$r_sql_3['razao_social']`, se realmente precisar de todo o conteúdo numa váriavel poderia simplesmente utilizar o [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php), que teria o mesmo efeito e sem o trabalho mecânico de ficar repetindo o trecho.

```
while ($r_sql_3 = mysql_fetch_row($sql_3)){

  list($id_empresa, $razao_social, $cep, $cidade, $uf, $rua, $numero, $bairro, $complemento, $logo, $cod_cli) = $r_sql_3;

  //...

}
```