# Lado a lado no Bootstrap, tá pulando linha

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema simples no Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5.

Faço uma busca no Banco de Dados, com informações. Ele alinha lado a lado mas, em alguns casos, uma linha é pulada, e fica só um item para a linha de baixo.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 style="text-align:left; color:white; margin:-top:1%;">Ação/Aventura</h2>

                    <?php

                    require 'conexao.php';

                    $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE categoria1 = 'acaoaventura' ORDER BY id ASC;");

                    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

                    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin:0;margin-bottom:3%;margin-top:2%;padding:0.1%;">

                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                            <a href="filme.php?id=<?php echo "$linha[id]";?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo "$linha[fotodacapa]"; ?>" class="img-fluid">                               
                                <p style="color:yellow; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><?php echo "$linha[nome]"; ?></p>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p style="color:white; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;">16 visitas</p></a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <a class="venobox_custom" data-type="youtube" href="https://youtu.be/<?php echo "$linha[trailer]"; ?>?autoplay=1"><p style="color:white; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><i class="fa fa-film" aria-hidden="true"></i> Trailer</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Neste trecho de código, eu faço a busca para mostrar na tela o que vem do banco, mas obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei trocar alguns itens de lugar, mas sem sucesso. Em um outro trabalho, consegui tirar o "container", algo não recomendado, mas funcionou para mim. Desta vez, não resolveu.

Alguma ideia dos amigos?

Agradeço antecipadamente!

Obs.: Não reparem nas configurações das Div's, como ainda estou testando, não organizei as classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **/!\ Isso é uma gambiarra!**

Você pode utilizar o `matchHeight` para que todos os elementos fiquem com o mesmo tamanho.

Obtenha em http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/, pode utilizar:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.0/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
```

Depois utilize:

```
$('.col-md-2').matchHeight();
```

Isso irá fazer todos os elementos `.col-md-2` possuírem a mesma altura, corrigindo o problema.

Este é o jeito mais simples de resolver isso caso esteja utilizando uma única `row` com elementos que excedem a largura da respectiva `row`.

Comment: Interessante solução, não a conhecia.

Comment: Eu também não. Estou tentando implantar aqui. Vai resolver grande parte dos meus problemas! Obrigado, @Inkeliz. Já respondo se consegui implantar.

Comment: Cara, isso é simplesmente perfeito! Resolveu aqui! Tudo encaixado! Solução bem bacana. Obrigado pelo suporte, @Inkeliz. Fica como referência aqui no SOPT, pois dei uma procurada e não achei solução para este problema!

Comment: Desculpe a sinceridade, mas não pulou de linha por causa da altura, isso que você fez foi praticamente uma gambiarra para evitar o problema, o sistema de `col-*-*` (grids) do bootstrap não funciona assim, está com problema na maneira que o AP usou, os `cols` só pode ir dentro de `row`, mas ele colocou `col` dentro de `col`, fora que a soma dos `cols` dentro de um `row` sempre deve ser 12.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu iria acrescentar a solução parecido com esta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179798/gerar-um-row-depois-de-2-colunas-no-bootstrap/179999#179999), adicionar `row` a cada 6 elementos, somando `12` no total no `md`. Entretanto como já havia uma coisa parecida resolvi acrescentar outra opção. Na minha opnião o problema continua sendo a altura, quando você tem alturas diferentes no mesmo `row` todo o `row` ficará a com a mesma altura, então o problema não irá existir. Posso editar acrescentando essa outra correção para complementar.

Comment: @Inkeliz tem muito mais problema do que só fazer a soma.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vou botar meu selo fashion de gambiarra nessa resposta.

Comment: Eu sugiro trocar o '.col-md-2' por um nome de classe válido. O ideal é criar uma classe para estes quadros de exibição e chama-lo como o Inkeliz disse: $('.classe-bloco').matchHeight();

Comment: @Inkeliz eu sei que já entendeu, é apenas para mostrar o problema, veja que listei 6 problemas no HTML dele http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180205/3635 (o 7 é extra)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentarei maneirar nas gambis, eu já tinha dado +1. Na verdade nem sabia que precisava do `row` sempre, porque pra mim já em algumas situações a margem do `col` podia ser útil, por exemplo, dentro de outro `col`.

Answer (score 7):

Não é assim que funciona os grids do bootstrap, a solução do [@inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180025/3635) funcionou mais por *coincidência*, mas não é a solução correta, ainda mais se tratando da maneira que você aplicou.

Como eu expliquei em [**Evitar quebra de linha (encavalando) em col-md bootstrap**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129074/3635), então os passos que deve seguir para usar GRIDs são basicamente:

1. Não use `col-` dentro de `col-`
2. O elemento "pai" do `col-` sempre deve ser um `row`
3. A soma de todos cols sempre deve ser `12`, por exemplo:

   - Se tiver 4 divs com a classe `.col-*-3` então a soma será 12 (3+3+3+3 = 12)
   - Se tiver 3 divs com a classe `.col-*-4` então a soma será 12 (4+4+4 = 12)
   - Também pode fazer `.col-*-6`+`.col-*-3`+`.col-*-3` por exemplo (6+3+3=12)

---

### Primeiro você explicar aonde estão os erros

Segue os problemas no teu HTML:

1. Você `<div class="col-md-2" style="margin:0;margin-bottom:3%;margin-top:2%;padding:0.1%;">` dentro de um `col-md-12`, como eu disse, `col-` sempre deve ir dentro de `row`, então está errado.
2. Você tem um `<div class="col-md-12" style="margin:0;padding:0;">` dentro de um `col-md-2`
3. Você tem dois `<div class="col-md-6">` dentro de `col-md-12`
4. A tag `<a>` está mal fechada: `<a href="filme.php?id=<?php echo "$linha[id]";?>">`, você colocou o `</a>` dentro outra tag, provavelmente para não conflitar com o link para o youtube. Mas isso está errado.
5. Tem dois `col` misturado a outros elementos HTML que não fazem parte da grid.
6. **Nunca**  altere as margens do um `col-` usando `margin:` ou `margin-left` ou `margin-right`, creio que top e bottom não tem problema.
7. **Extra:** Apesar de não afetar os grids tem um erro no seu CSS está errado `h2 style="text-align:left; color:white; margin:-top:1%;`, tem um `margin:-top`, o correto é `margin-top:1%;`

---

### Como resolver

Como expliquei aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180194/3635 sendo PHP você pode usar algo como `$i % (numero de colunas desejada), no seu caso você usou "col-md-2"` então creio que você queira **6 colunas por linhas**

Deve ficar assim:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- aqui está certo total é igual 12 -->
        <h2 style="text-align:left; color:white; margin:-top:1%;">Ação/Aventura</h2>

        <?php
        require 'conexao.php';

        $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE categoria1 = 'acaoaventura' ORDER BY id ASC;");

        while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $i = 0;

        while ($i < 20) {

        $needarow = !($i % 6);
        $i++;//Deve vir depois
        ?>

        <?php if ($needarow) { ?>
        <?php if ($i > 1) { ?>

        </div> <!-- //fecha .row -->

        <?php } ?>

        <div class="row">

        <?php }?>

            <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom:3%;margin-top:2%;padding:0.1%;">

                <!--//acho que nem precisa de col aqui -->
                <a href="filme.php?id=<?php echo $linha['id'];?>">

                    <img src="" class="img-fluid">
                    <p style="color:yellow; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><?php echo $linha['nome']; ?></p>
                </a> <!-- Link fechado -->

                <div class="row"> <!--// Row necessário para adicionar -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>16 visitas</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a class="venobox_custom" data-type="youtube" href="https://youtu.be/<?php echo $linha[trailer]; ?>?autoplay=1"><p><i class="fa fa-film" aria-hidden="true"></i> Trailer</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
        }   //Termina o loop
        ?>

        </div> <!-- //fecha o ultimo .row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uma super aula, agradeço pela atenção. Deixei a "gambiarra" por hora, por causa da pressa do meu amigo em terminar o projeto, mas vou em busca de estudar muito mais para estar aplicando de forma correta. Vou tomar sua resposta como referências futuras. Mais uma vez, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: @HebertRichard obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Coloque uma altura **IGUAL** para todos elementos marcados com col-md-2.

PS: usar styling no HTML é altamente não aconselhável, é por isso que o Bootstrap está aí, para você não precisar fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta! Bem, em relação ao estilo, gosto de criar um arquivo "styles.css" para deixar as alterações que desejo, o código fica mais limpo para ser lido. Em relação ao col-md-2, é apenas 1 que tem na página, buscando todos os id'ss que estão no banco. Não tenho div's diferentes, apenas esta, na página toda.

Comment: Sim, mas o while está repetindo-o conforme o número de resultados. Esse problema acontece porque cada col-md-2 tem uma altura diferente, assim quando ele pula uma linha e fica só com um col-md-2, é tentado "encaixar" aonde couber. Por isso, vai no col-md-2 que você tem e coloca um `height: 300px` (valor estimado). Isso com certeza deve resolver.

Comment: Não gostaria de trabalhar com tamanho fixo, com medo de perder a responsividade.

Answer (score 1):

A principio, o problema esta quando a sua consulta resulta em um titulo com 2 linhas e outro com 1 apenas, isso causa o desalinhamento e acaba fazendo com que pule uma linha.

Tem algumas opções para resolver:

Criar uma largura maior de forma que os textos não fiquem em 2 linhas, ou criar um margin padrão na altura dos quadrados foto e titulo.

para assim manterem eles alinhados.

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta. Em relação ao texto, concordo totalmente com você. O problema é que ninguém quer essa limitação, o que dificulta na hora de resolver isso. Já tive um problema semelhante, quando desenvolvia um jornal. Já modifiquei as margins, mesmo assim, o problema persiste. De repente, não estou entendendo sua colocação.

Comment: sim eu me expressei mal, mas pense assim, seria possível criar um bloco coma s divs unindo imagem e texto em um único grupo, como se fosse o bloco, então você configuraria o tamanho do bloco no css e pronto todos teriam os mesmos tamanhos, tipo aqueles com titulo menores sobraria um pouco mais de espaço e aqueles com títulos maiores preencheriam todo o espaço. Você consegue entender minha ideia?

Comment: Entendi sim, meu amigo. Vou estudar um pouco mais, para evitar tais transtornos. Cometi erros nesse site, mas para o cliente está tudo ok, ele não vê as gambiarras no momento. De qualquer forma, vou melhorar o código em 1 ou 2 semanas, após terminar outros trabalhos já em andamento. Obrigado pela atenção!