# O que faz esse código?

Tags: php

```
<?php $campo == "Não Informado" ?: $campo = ''; ?>
```

Na minha teoria se campo for igual a Não Informado retornará campo como vazio senão manterá o valor, estou certo?

Comment: Esse é o operador elvis

Comment: O Operador Ternário é uma tecnica para tornar o código mais simples possível.
Ou seja, o operador ternário veio para facilitar. Recomendo que você dê uma estudada sobre operador ternário neste link [Link que fala sobre o Operador Ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/uso-de-e-em-php) Vai te ajudar muito.

Answer (score 5):

Esse código é bem confuso, mas faz uma coisa simples: se o valor de `$campo` for `"Não Informado"`, transforma o valor do campo em `''`.

A primeira coisa executada nesse código é `$campo == "Não informado"`. Isso dá `false` e a expressão se torna `false ?: $campo = ''`. A partir daí é um operador ternário `?:` "normal", porém com o segundo termo (que executa se o primeiro for `true`) em branco.

Uma maneira bem mais clara de escrever o mesmo código, também em uma linha, seria:

```
 if($campo == "Não Informado") $campo = '';
```

No seu exemplo original, o operador ternário está sendo usado para controle de fluxo, que não é a função ideal dele. Isso costuma causar confusão.