# Preenchendo index de resultados inexistentes de um select com 0

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array, foreach, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu faço um `select` no banco de dados do qual me retorna um `array` de dados. Com isso, faço o seguinte `foreach` no mesmo:

```
foreach ($resultado4 as $key => $value7) {  
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = $value7['floresqtd'];
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = $value7['isaqtd'];
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = $value7['uniqtd'];
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = $value7['floresvalor'];
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = $value7['isavalor'];
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = $value7['univalor'];
}
```

Algumas vezes, acontece de um dos indexes do select vir com nenhum resultado, no caso o index Z, não existir. Quando acontecesse isso, queria colocar os valor desse index inexistente como 0, assim criando ele e atribuindo o valor 0, pois preciso dele para realizar algumas contas que não entra na questão. Até agora não consegui formular nenhuma lógica para realizar o mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, você pode verificar se o index esta setado antes de atribuir o valor usando a função [isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) junto com [operadores ternários](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Nesse link [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56812/uso-de-e-em-php) tem mais informações.

```
// php <= 5.6
foreach ($resultado4 as $key => $value7) {
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = isset($value7['floresqtd']) ? $value7['floresqtd'] : 0;
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = isset($value7['isaqtd']) ? $value7['isaqtd'] : 0;
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = isset($value7['uniqtd']) ? $value7['uniqtd'] : 0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = isset($value7['floresvalor']) ? $value7['floresvalor'] : 0.0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = isset($value7['isavalor']) ? $value7['isavalor'] : 0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = isset($value7['univalor']) ? $value7['univalor'] : 0;
}

// php >= 7.x
foreach ($resultado4 as $key => $value7) {
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = $value7['floresqtd'] ?? 0;
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = $value7['isaqtd'] ?? 0;
    $array6[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = $value7['uniqtd'] ?? 0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'flores'] = $value7['floresvalor'] ?? 0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'isa'] = $value7['isavalor'] ?? 0;
    $array8[$value7['carteira'].'uni'] = $value7['univalor'] ?? 0;
}
```

Outra opção também seria alterar a query para pegar o valor da coluna se não for null caso contrário pega um valor definido por você no caso 0. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT id, 
   IF(valor IS NOT NULL, valor, 0)
FROM tabela
```