# Existe alguma forma de reduzir os if's do meu código?

Tags: php, sql, estilo-de-codificação

```
function updateUser($usuario, $senha, $adm){
    //Atualiza informações sobre o usuário
    $sql_query; 
    $q_senha = ""; 
    $q_adm = "";
    $dot = "";
    if(!empty($senha)){
        $q_senha = "senha=md5('$senha')";
    }
    if($adm != NULL){
        $q_adm = "adm='$adm'";
    }
    if($adm != NULL and !empty($senha)){
        $dot = ",";
    }
    $sql_query = "update tb_users set ".$q_senha.$dot." ".$q_adm." where usuario='$usuario';";
    return $this->execute($sql_query);
}
```

Eu sei que é uma situação simples e pelo que eu li o Strategy é uma forma eficiente para casos com muitos if's, e que não é  meu caso. Mas eu acredito que tenha alguma forma de reduzir através de um bom uso do SQL. Mas não achei nada na internet a respeito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem como você usar operador ternário, segue o exemplo:

```
function updateUser($usuario, $senha, $adm){
    //Atualiza informações sobre o usuário
    $q_senha = (!empty($senha)) ? "senha=md5('$senha')" : "";
    $q_adm = ($adm != NULL) ? "adm='$adm'" : "";
    $dot = ($adm != NULL and !empty($senha)) ? "," : "";

    $sql_query = "update tb_users set ".$q_senha.$dot." ".$q_adm." where usuario='$usuario';";
    return $this->execute($sql_query);
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre o operador ternário [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56814/57573).

Comment: A sua alternativa torna visualmente fica bem mais elegante, mas eu gostaria de saber se há um script diferente para não fazer essa gambiarra. É assim que eu a vejo kkk

Comment: Não é desnecessário `$sql_query;` no início do método!?

Comment: Sim, é sim @rbz.

Comment: @MatheusHenrique isso acaba tornando sua pergunta ampla demais.

Comment: @MatheusHenrique Não tem como sabermos qual a melhor forma e até mesmo se é "gambiarra" o que fez, uma vez que, não temos todo seu código. A forma que o Junior fez já "diminuiu" como queria.

Comment: @rbz, ambas as formas usam 3 condicionais o que me faz pensar que não houve redução.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Então, coloquei aspas em "diminuiu", pois diminuiu visualmente. rs Mas é verdade, não reduziu condições.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Levei em consideração a parte do título da pergunta onde está descrito "reduzir if's". O que de fato foi feito, os if's foram trocados por operadores ternários.

Comment: Bom, realmente o que da pra melhorar é trocar os if's por operadores ternários. Muito obrigado Junior e a todos.