# Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\aula\exercicio\update.php on line 11

Tags: php

Galera estou com um problema com essa mensagem de erro,verifiquei a conexão com o banco de dados e esta certo eu consigo cadastrar mas na hora de dar update ele da esse erro e não consigo descobrir

Segue o código do update:

```
    ?php 
    include "conexao.php";
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $id = $_POST['id'] : mysqli_close($conect);
        $cpf = (isset($_POST['cpf'])) ? $cpf = $_POST['cpf'] : mysqli_close($conect);
        $nome = (isset($_POST['nome'])) ? $nome = $_POST['nome'] : mysqli_close($conect);
        $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $email = $_POST['email'] : mysqli_close($conect);
        $telefone = (isset($_POST['telefone'])) ? $telefone = $_POST['telefone'] : mysqli_close($conect);
        $sql = "UPDATE cadastro SET cpf = '$cpf',nome = '$nome',email = '$email',telefone = '$telefone'
        WHERE id = '$id' ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);


        var_dump($id);
        var_dump($cpf);
        var_dump($nome);
        var_dump($email);
        var_dump($telefone);
    }
    else{

        header("Location:cadastro.php");
    }

?>
```

Segue a conexão:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$psw= "";
$db = "exercicio";
$conect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$psw,$db);
$charset = mysqli_set_charset($conect,"utf8");
 ?>
```

Comment: Você está usando o operador ternário como se fosse um `if/else. Ele funciona como um if. Ele testa uma condição (o primeiro operando), se ela for verdadeira, o resultado da operação é o primeiro valor (após o ?, o segundo operando), se ela for falsa, então o resultado é o segundo valor (depois do :, o terceiro operando). Leia essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56814/137387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta executando o `mysqli_close` antes da query, nem faz sentido executar ali, o correto é executa-lo após o mysqli_query, ou melhor após tudo necessário.

Na verdade tem uma série de erros no seu código, até a maneira que setou as variáveis não tem sentido, não esqueça de escapar as variáveis com `mysqli_real_escape_string`, deveria ser assim:

```
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) : '';
$cpf = (isset($_POST['cpf'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['cpf']) : '';
$nome = (isset($_POST['nome'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']) : '';
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';
$telefone = (isset($_POST['telefone'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telefone']) : '';

$sql = "UPDATE cadastro SET cpf = '$cpf',nome = '$nome',email = '$email',telefone = '$telefone'
    WHERE id = '$id' ";

$query = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);

mysqli_close($conect);
```

Comment: obrigado corrigi esta tudo normal agora