# Validação de variável

Tags: php, operadores, condição

Eu vi alguns exemplos de verificação de variável para setar valores.

Por exemplo:

```
$nome ?? "Tem nome";
$nome or "Tem nome";
```

No caso, tem como fazer a validação ao contrário?

Eu gostaria de fazer algo desse tipo:

```
if(!$nome) ? "Não tem nome";
```

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor, porque do jeito que você explicou é exatamente o que a condição já está fazendo. Quando vc usa `$nome ?? "Tem nome"` você está dizendo que se existir algum valor na variável vc vai usar ela, se não use o outro como default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta não diz o que deseja obter de resultado. A primeira linha de código obterá o texto se a variável não existir ou tiver um valor nulo e só faz sentido usar como parte de uma expressão maior, geralmente guardar o resultado na própria variável sendo avaliada. A segunda linha não obtém como resultado o texto, então eles não são equivalentes, ele resulta em 0 ou 1, a questão ali é só determinar se o segundo operando do `or` será avaliado ou não, mas avaliar é diferente de pegar esse valor como resultado, no casos o resultado em casos assim sempre será 1.

O terceiro código que quer fazer não faz sentido poque parece que deseja que se não tiver nada fique com nada e se tiver alguma coisa deve mudar o conteúdo. Isto sequer é uma validação. Mas poderia fazer assim:

Use o [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56812/101) normal:

```
$nome ? $nome : "Não tem nome"
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/itdGw4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ContionalInverted). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ConditionalInverted.php).