# Concatenar string de variáveis

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Estou com um problema, preciso concatenar umas variáveis aqui em PHP e elas são strings, mas o problema é que elas estão dentro de "ifs" então quando não é setada, diz que a variável é *undefined* na hora de concatenar. A baixo meu código:

```
if ($sinal==="sim" || $parcelada==='sim' || $vista==='sim' || $automovel==='sim' || $_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim' || $entrada==="sim" || $fgts==="sim" || $financiado==="sim"){

        $p20 = ': O valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, caput) fica inalterável,
independentemente de qualquer alteração que sofra o valor';
if($sinal==='sim'){
    $p21 = ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
} if($parcelada==='sim'){
    $p22 = ' da parcela (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($parceladaValorTexto , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($entrada==="sim"){
    $p23 = ' da entrada (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($entradaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($vista==='sim'){
    $p24 = ' do valor à vista (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($vistaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($fgts==="sim"){
    $p25 = ' do FGTS (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($fgtsValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($automovel==='sim'){
    $p26 = ' do valor do automóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($automovelValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim'){
    $p27 = ' do valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($imovelPagValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($financiado==="sim"){
    $p28 = ' do valor financiado (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($financiadoValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).')';
} 

$paragrafo2 = $p20.$p21.$p21.$p22.$p23.$p24.$p25.$p26.$p27.$p28.';' ; //aqui esta o problema, ele concatena elas sempre, porem quando um if e falso a variavel dele fica undefined.

    array_push($paragrafos, $paragrafo2);
}
```

Comment: Augusto, já pensou em inicializar todas elas com um valor de string vazio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não entrar no IF o valor de sua variável está udefined. Antes de tudo inicie suas variáveis com valores vazios:

```
/* Código a ser adicionado*/
    $p20="";
    $p21="";
    $p21="";
    $p22="";
    $p23="";
    $p24="";
    $p25="";
    $p26="";
    $p27="";
    $p28="";

    if ($sinal==="sim" || $parcelada==='sim' || $vista==='sim' || $automovel==='sim' || $_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim' || $entrada==="sim" || $fgts==="sim" || $financiado==="sim"){

            $p20 = ': O valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, caput) fica inalterável,
    independentemente de qualquer alteração que sofra o valor';
    if($sinal==='sim'){
        $p21 = ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    } if($parcelada==='sim'){
        $p22 = ' da parcela (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($parceladaValorTexto , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($entrada==="sim"){
        $p23 = ' da entrada (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($entradaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($vista==='sim'){
        $p24 = ' do valor à vista (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($vistaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($fgts==="sim"){
        $p25 = ' do FGTS (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($fgtsValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($automovel==='sim'){
        $p26 = ' do valor do automóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($automovelValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim'){
        $p27 = ' do valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($imovelPagValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }if($financiado==="sim"){
        $p28 = ' do valor financiado (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($financiadoValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).')';
    } 

    $paragrafo2 = $p20.$p21.$p21.$p22.$p23.$p24.$p25.$p26.$p27.$p28.';' ; //aqui esta o problema, ele concatena elas sempre, porem quando um if e falso a variavel dele fica undefined.

        array_push($paragrafos, $paragrafo2);
    }
```

Uma outra forma de fazer é utilizando apenas uma variável para concatenar:

```
$paragrafo2="";

if ($sinal==="sim" || $parcelada==='sim' || $vista==='sim' || $automovel==='sim' || $_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim' || $entrada==="sim" || $fgts==="sim" || $financiado==="sim"){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.': O valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, caput) fica inalterável,independentemente de qualquer alteração que sofra o valor';
if($sinal==='sim'){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
} if($parcelada==='sim'){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' da parcela (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($parceladaValorTexto , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($entrada==="sim"){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' da entrada (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($entradaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($vista==='sim'){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do valor à vista (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($vistaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($fgts==="sim"){
     $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do FGTS (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($fgtsValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($automovel==='sim'){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do valor do automóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($automovelValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim'){
     $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($imovelPagValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
}if($financiado==="sim"){
    $paragrafo2 = $paragrafo2.' do valor financiado (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($financiadoValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).')';
} 

array_push($paragrafos, $paragrafo2);
```

Comment: nossa nao acredito que nao pensei nisso kkkk muito obrigado ! salvou1

Answer (score 3):

Coloque um `else` em cada `if` e inicialize as variáveis com o valor `''` assim sempre terá um valor.

Inclusive os `if´s estão encavalados.

Na verdade seria até melhor usar o [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56812/101) e provavelmente um *array* no lugar de tantas variáveis e concatenar em um laço. Dá para usar *array* em outros pontos também. Faça algo assim:

```
$p21 = $sinal === 'sim' ? $p21 = ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),' : '';
```

Melhor ainda:

```
$p[21] = $sinal === 'sim' ? $p21 = ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6) + 1).'),' : '';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ConditionalConcat.php).

Comment: muito obrigado !

Comment: Veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.